# How filling only a input of two inputs with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have five input with one class named cheque . How can I fill only a input of five inputs with **jQuery** ?

I can`t using validator **jQuery** library .

This is html file :

```
<input class="cheque" id="chmomtaz" placeholder="ریال" type="text" style="width: 100%" >
<input class="cheque" id="chkimia" placeholder="ریال" type="text" style="width: 100%" >
<input class="cheque" id="chrash" placeholder="ریال" type="text" style="width: 100%" >
<input class="cheque" id="chsandal" placeholder="ریال" type="text" style="width: 100%" >
<input class="cheque" id="chchob" placeholder="ریال" type="text" style="width: 100%" >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@hasan movahed your solution will work but, if I understand your needs, this way:

```
$('.cheque').on("keyup", function() {
    $('.cheque').not(this).val('');
});
```

This will delete all other inputs content without disabling them

Answer (score 0):

i find this problem .

try it :

```
$('.cheque').on("keyup", function() {
  $('.cheque').not(this).prop('disabled', this.value.length === 0 ? false : true);
});
```

Comment: This will disable all checks except for the one you clicked. After first check you will not be able to change your choice!

Comment: @ehsan khob khili donbal javab gashtam goftam shayad be kar aksi byad .